# Is there a lower_bound() function in C++ for long long data type?

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search, lower-bound

`pos` is an iterator to the lower bound of `q`. Here `q` is a long long integer and `prefix` is a vector which stores long long elements.

```
vector <int> :: iterator pos; 
pos = lower_bound(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), q);
```

I get the following error:

```
no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>> = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long *, std::vector<long long, std::allocator<long long>>>
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: how have you declared pos? It's likely that your declaration of `pos` is incorrect

Comment: ```vector <int> :: iterator pos; ```

Comment: `vector<int>` and `vector<long long>` are different types. You can't assign an iterator of one of those to an iterator the other one, hence the error. Declare `pos` as `vector<long long>::iterator pos;`, `decltype(prefix)::iterator pos;` or `auto pos = lower_bound(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), q);` (since C++11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration of `pos` is incorrect. You vector - `prefix` is of declared as `vector<long long>prefix;`. The iterator should also be of the same type.

You can try using the following -

```
vector<long long>::iterator pos = lower_bound(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), q);
```

You can always choose the following syntax as well if you are not sure of how to declare the variable(iterator in this case) properly :

```
auto pos = lower_bound(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), q);
```

The `auto` keyword can only be used in C++11 and above. But, if you are sure of the syntax and type of the variable you are declaring, it's always **preferable to declare it manually** rather than having it inferred by your program. It will **increase the reliability as well as readability** of your program.

Hope this solves your issue !

Comment: That did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @Nishchay Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted